# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not updating item indexes when data deleted

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a list of items with each item having a name and a delete button.

My **populateViewHolder** method

```
  @Override
  protected void populateViewHolder(SubChannelViewHolder viewHolder, final SubChannel model, final int position) {

    //passing a clickListener to viewHolder,viewHolder in turn decides to which view it should assign this clickListener.
    viewHolder.bindToSubChannel(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String key= getRef(position).getKey();//Getting the key of the subChannel item

        Map<String,Object> childUpdates=new HashMap<>();

       //The positions where the subChannel was stored
       childUpdates.put("/channels-subChannels/"+mChannelKey+"/" +key+"/subChannelName/",null);
       childUpdates.put("/channels/" + mChannelKey+"/subChannels/"+key+"/subChannelName/", null);
       childUpdates.put("/user-channels/" +getUid()+"/"+ mChannelKey+"/subChannels/"+key+"/subChannelName/", null);

       //setting values at these location as null thereby doing batch deleting.
       mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
     }
   });
 }
```

My **ViewHolder**  : inside my ViewHolder I have a **bindToSubChannel** method which takes the object retrieved by the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter & sets the clickListener on the delete ImageView.

```
public class SubChannelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  private TextView subChannelNameTextView;
  private ImageView removeImageView;

  public SubChannelViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    subChannelNameTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subChannel_name_text_view);
    removeImageView =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_image_view);
  }
  public void bindToSubChannel(SubChannel subChannel,View.OnClickListener RemoveImageClickListener){
    subChannelNameTextView.setText(subChannel.getSubChannelName());
    removeImageView.setOnClickListener(RemoveImageClickListener);
  }
}
```

I get the following **IndexOutOfBoundsException** at this line:

```
String key= getRef(position).getKey();
```

The Exception is thrown when say I had 6 items in the list(1,2,3,4,5,6) &  I deleted 1,2.

Then when I press delete for 6 the index the adapter retrieves for item 6 is the original 6 but but the size of the adapter had changed to 4(after deletion of 1,2)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.arnavvohra.arry2, PID: 1493
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.getItem(FirebaseArray.java:52)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
at in.arnavvohra.arry2.EditSubChannelsActivity$2$1.onClick(EditSubChannelsActivity.java:67)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

How should I go about solving this issue?

Comment: You should not have to call `notifyItemRemoved()` or similar on the adapter. Just delete the items from the database and the rest happens automatically.

Comment: Initially I had removed them but searching SO I found that they should be added.
Anyways, my error remains even if I remove them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can u or someone in your team help?

Comment: There are a lot of parts missing in the code right now. Can you provide a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Don't just copy from your existing app, but reproduce the problem from scratch with the minimum code necessary.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have tried to add as much code as required(hope it's not too boring to read it) ,added comments & explained where the error is occurring.
Can you have a look at it.

Comment: Dropping in to say thanks a bunch for posting this query. I was treating click listener to wrong way after seeing @ArnavVohra 's usage. Passing the click back to holder class is far better!

Comment: @Paritosh Welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than considering `position` to be final when binding the `ViewHolder`, instead create a final reference to the key:

```
  @Override
  protected void populateViewHolder(SubChannelViewHolder viewHolder, final SubChannel model, int position) {

    // Move this out here, mark it as final.  Then reference it inside the block.
    final String Key = getRef(position).getKey();

    //passing a clickListener to viewHolder,viewHolder in turn decides to which view it should assign this clickListener.
    viewHolder.bindToSubChannel(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       Map<String,Object> childUpdates=new HashMap<>();

       //The positions where the subChannel was stored
       childUpdates.put("/channels-subChannels/"+mChannelKey+"/" +key+"/subChannelName/",null);
       childUpdates.put("/channels/" + mChannelKey+"/subChannels/"+key+"/subChannelName/", null);
       childUpdates.put("/user-channels/" +getUid()+"/"+ mChannelKey+"/subChannels/"+key+"/subChannelName/", null);

       //setting values at these location as null thereby doing batch deleting.
       mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
     }
   });
 }
```